# What does `System Preferences.app` sync to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, system-settings

If we go into System Preferences → Internet Accounts → iCloud → iCloud Drive (Options…), we’ll see `System Preferences.app` is syncing with iCloud.

[image]

What exactly is it syncing? I’ve just performed a fresh install on my machine (El Capitan to Sierra) and none of my settings carried over. So what is this doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched alot about that and enden up talking with apple's support. They told me that this setting allows to sync Universal Access settings and things like the fact that terms of use were accepted (shown when accessing first time to some apple's apps). And some other things (not asked what exactly). I asked about hotkeys settings in Keyboard menu - they told me that it is not synced.

Answer (score 4):

It is syncing your system preferences. The reason you did not see anything happen is that your former system was running El Capitan. The new sync feature only works with Sierra.

So if you had a Sierra Mac and then bought a new Sierra Mac and signed in on iCloud, you could sync over your system preferences from the old Mac.

Comment: All all preferences synced, or just a subset? And if the latter, what's excluded?

Comment: @BallpointBen Just tried it on a VM, and absolutely no preferences were synchronised, despite everything being checked.